# Conditional formatting only values in range in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have these values in A1:C16 in Excel:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NA | NA | NA |
| 3,18E-04 | NA | NA |
| 3,75E-03 | 1,03E-10 | NA |
| 5,67E+01 | 7,95E+02 | 9,61E-16 |
| 9,25E-01 | 9,85E-02 | 2,04E-01 |
| 7,80E-02 | 1,10E-03 | 3,04E-01 |
| 5,29E-60 | 1,09E-144 | 1,61E-251 |
| 3,59E-43 | 9,07E-93 | 5,62E-230 |
| 1,16E+09 | 4,23E+08 | 1,43E+09 |
| 8,52E-01 | 7,71E-01 | 6,95E-01 |
| 9,80E+09 | 3,68E+08 | 2,79E-04 |
| 2,21E-01 | 9,84E-01 | 4,99E-02 |
| 4,88E+00 | 6,18E-02 | 1,89E-02 |
| 1,67E-03 | 3,50E-04 | 9,68E-03 |
| 6,31E-29 | 5,41E-58 | 5,04E-98 |
| 8,39E-14 | 8,68E-24 | 2,84E-15 |

What I need to do is to colour scale only values between the minimum value (1,61E-251) and 0,05. Can anyone help me, explaining the process step by step?

Comment: Refer to this support article: https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/excel-chat/excel-tutorial/conditional-formatting/highlight-values-between

Answer (score 2):

select cell A1,
choose conditional formating select "enter formula"
choose define formula
enter
=(and ( A1>1,61e-251; A1<0,05))

Then choose the appropriate formating.
The formula is either true or false.

Last step, copy the cell and past the format to the other cells.

Comment: Thank you r2d3, but this seems not to be the solution, because when I have to choose the appropriate formating I can't choose a color scale, but only a two-colors format (i.e. green or white, without intermediates). But I need to color scale values between 1,61e-251 and 0,05 so that the more a value is near to 0,05, the more its cell colour filling will be dark coloured.

Comment: I apologize for ignoring the term color scale. As I only have Office 2000 at home, I can't look that information up right now. I don't know if a color scale is possible as a simple solution. You could emulate a small scale by defining buckets so that the conditions only gets true for one unique bucket. Then you would simply define different background colors - having one formular for each color.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a Named Range for the area to be format (or use absolute addressing in the formula if you prefer)

[image]

- Set three different formula based formatting rules, and select `Stop if True` for each one.

eg:

```
=PERCENTRANK(IF(myRng<=0.05,myRng,""),A1)<=0.25
=PERCENTRANK(IF(myRng<=0.05,myRng,""),A1)<=0.75
=PERCENTRANK(IF(myRng<=0.05,myRng,""),A1)>0.75
```

*Depending on the gradients you want, you could use more rules with smaller deviations between, or apply the two color gradient to each rule, or whatever*

[image]

[image]